# XP software restrictions policy, disable message dialog every time software is restricted.

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy

I have created some "Additional Rules", in "Software Restriction Policies".  The rules work as expected, but I get a dialog message box every time they disallow the specified application.

How can I disable this message box from being displayed?  Is this possible?  For specific "Additional Rules"?  If not even a blanket configuration, preventing all these type of messages is acceptable.  They are almost worse than the software my "Additional Rules" prevents from executing.

I would very much appreciate any help, regarding my question.

Comment: I'm upvoting as I think this is an interesting question and I would like to know the answer. As far as I know, this is not possible with Group Policy. Perhaps someone will indicate a third-party app, but I suspect the dialog is there to indicate to the user that the execution was explicitly blocked, rather than having them double-click the shortcut over and over.

Comment: The only way I could deal with it, was removing my restrictions and removing said executables. I had to use something else entirely, basically if you want to prevent a part of an application from executing... Look elsewhere unless the messages are actually an improvement.  In my situation, The messages were worse than what I intended to restrict.  I would still like to know, if it's possible to preventing those messages.  I suspect a 3rd party tool would be the only appropriate solution, I've seen something like that in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows XP does not have this feature build-in, as far as I've read during investigation.

A 3rd party solution is required, and although I never found one as described, I'm sure one exists.